# How to run MSSQL t-sql in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I created a t-sql code in mssql server but now i need to run following code in the mysql server

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON;
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON;
create procedure [dbo].[SpearmanCorrelation] as
with RankedSampleData(ID,positiveFactor,negativeFactor,rank_positiveFactor,rank_negativeFactor) as (
select ID,positiveFactor,negativeFactor,rank() over (order by positiveFactor) +(count(*) over (partition by positiveFactor) - 1)/2.0,rank() over (order by negativeFactor) +(count(*) over (partition by negativeFactor) - 1)/2.0
from MainFactor1_SampleData
)
select 1e0 -(6*sum(square(rank_positiveFactor-rank_negativeFactor))/count(*)/(square(count(*)) - 1))
from RankedSampleData;
```

but i got this error message

```
SQL query:

SET ANSI_NULLS ON ;

MySQL said: Documentation
#1193 - Unknown system variable 'ANSI_NULLS'
```

how can i run this in mysql server?

Comment: In MySQL, by default ANSI_NULLS  is ON.

Comment: Create a linked server to the MySQL database and run the stored procedure in SQL Server (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190479.aspx).  You'll probably have to access it using ODBC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Get the MySql source code
- Change it to accept TSQL

This is the ONLY way to make MySql understand TSQL (which is what you ask - you do not ask how to fix it, you ask how to make MySql not throw an error for this SQL).

Alternatively you realize that they are different dialects, sit down and rewrite the SQL.

Given that the first line is setting option - reading the documentation and trying out the other statements will likely make you realize you likely do not need it at all.